# ffmpeg: how to replace img_convert() with sws_scale()

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I have an old version FFmpeg code like this ：

```
int ret = img_convert((AVPicture *)picture, c->pix_fmt,
                      (AVPicture *)input_picture, (PixelFormat)input_pix_fmt,
                      width, height);
if (ret < 0)
        return false;
```

I noticed that in new ffmpeg, the **img_convert()** has been replaced by **sws_scale()**, I followed the format and change like this:

```
int w = width;
int h = height;

static struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx 
                = sws_getContext(w, h, (PixelFormat)input_pix_fmt, 
                                 w, h, c->pix_fmt, 
                                 SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

int ret = sws_scale(img_convert_ctx,
                    input_picture->data, 
                    input_picture->linesize,
                    0,
                    height, 
                    (AVPicture *)picture, 
                    (AVPicture *)picture);

if (ret < 0) {
   return false;
}

sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);
```

but it gives the error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘AVPicture*’ to ⏎
       ‘uint8_t* const* {aka unsigned char* const*}’ for argument ‘6’ to ⏎
       ‘int sws_scale(SwsContext*, const uint8_t* const*, ⏎
       const int*, int, int, uint8_t* const*, const int*)’
```

It seems the error falls in the **last two parameters** of sws_scale. How should I modify it?

And is it caused by **c and c++ incompatible** problem? I am now run FFmpeg in C, and use **extern C** to include the headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sws_scale doesn't have a concept of AVPicture. Rather you pass the data lines and linesize lines. Which is

```
sws_scale(
    img_convert_ctx,
    input_picture->data, 
    input_picture->linesize,
    0,
    height, 
    picture->data,
    picture->linesize
);
```

By the way you can copy the `AVPicture` structure around so there is no reason to use pointers.